# How to compress a large amount of file in hdfs by a distributed method?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, gzip

I recently need to compress hundreds of file in hdfs. Now I can use GNU parallel to work on one node by multi-process. However my servers dont allow ssh between each other to make it distributed. Therefore now I am seeking a distributed framework to do my work. Are hadoop, spark or flink convenient to compress those files on multiple nodes? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you `ssh` to all hosts from the master server? If so get the list of files to the master server, start GNU Parallel from the master server with each of the slave servers given in `-S` (or `--slf`).

Comment: No i cannot, so I'd like to put filename in a message queue then fetch file and execute compression.